# Green/Blue deployment with ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-code-deploy, blue-green-deployment

I want to do a green/blue deployment using ECS.

In other words I want to be able go from version v1 of the app to v2. Not a rolling update where during the deployment, some users may see v1, while others see v2.

AWS supports this here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create-blue-green.html

Note that I am using the AWS Web Console (Not the CLI) to do this.

I can follow most of the instructions, but when I set the CodeDeploy deployment I get the following error:

> Deployment group's ECS service must be configured for a CODE_DEPLOY deployment controller.

There is no option for blue/green deployment when creating the service in the new console page in ECS:

[image]

However this option is available in the classic console version (which is soon to be removed), but the option is greyed out:

[image]

Surely there is a easy way to do green/blue deployments using ECS.

*Update*
I managed to get this to work on the CLI however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's on the roadmap, you can use [this](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/2112) ticket to track the progress

Comment: Worth mentioning the old UI needs fixing as well until this is added to the new UI.

Answer (score 0):

Another known issue:

https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/2157

Hoepefully will be fixed in the new UI.

For now stick to console commands.